# How to configure and run celerybeat

Tags: python, celery, celerybeat

I am just getting started with celery,trying to run a periodic task.

Configured *rabbitmq** added celeryconfig.py.

And added following code in tasks.py:

```
from celery.decorators import periodic_task
from datetime import timedelta

@periodic_task(run_every=timedelta(seconds=2))
def every_2_seconds():
    print("Running periodic task!")
```

Now when I start celerybeat by typing "celerybeat" in my terminal it starts to run with follwing message

```
celerybeat 
celerybeat v3.0.3 (Chiastic Slide) is starting.
__    -    ... __   -        _
Configuration ->
    . broker -> amqp://arnold@localhost:5672//
    . loader -> celery.loaders.default.Loader
    . scheduler -> celery.beat.PersistentScheduler
    . db -> celerybeat-schedule
    . logfile -> [stderr]@INFO
    . maxinterval -> now (0s)
[2012-08-03 14:24:52,202: INFO/MainProcess] Celerybeat: Starting...
```

And there is no output of `every_2_seconds` method in the terminal.I am assuming I have to specify which app to run or wich tasks during the celerybeat command.How to do that?

How can I specify tasks and print the line after every 2 seconds as a periodic tasks?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `CELERY_IMPORTS=("tasks",)` to your celeryconfig.py then run celerybeat.

Comment: Also run celeryd that will print "Running periodic task!" after every two seconds.

Comment: Hey @mushfiq - can you help here, I'm running celery beat via celery multi with --beat and --schedule options however no tasks are being executed. I tried decorating task with `@app.periodic_task` with `CELERY_IMPORTS=("tasks",)` but no success.

Comment: @Greg0ry your broker is up? Which version of Celery you are running?

Comment: I found it - in the end it was my mistake of declaring CELERY_IMPORTS incorrectly (it should be app.conf/CELERY_IMPORTS of course). Thanks!