# celery.beat: periodic tasks on windows

Tags: celery

I am trying to get running the periodic tasks on celery with beat.

I tried to do it the same way it is described here: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#beat-entries
Maybe it is because I am not quite sure where to put the files and how exactly to import everything..

Or maybe it's also because of a wrong timezone (I tried several things here though).

I put everything in one file:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import time
import job_example
from celery import Celery
from datetime import timedelta
from celery.schedules import crontab

CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'add-every-30-seconds': {
        'task': 'tasks.add',
        #'schedule': crontab(hour=15, minute=30, day_of_week=1),
        #'schedule': crontab(), # execute every minute
        'schedule': timedelta(seconds=30),
        'args': (15, 16),
    },
}

CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Europe/Berlin'
# CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'UTC'

app = Celery(include=['tasks'])

app.conf.update(
    BROKER_URL='amqp://localhost//',
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='db+postgresql://postgres:1234@localhost:5432/test_lukas',
    CELERYD_TASK_TIME_LIMIT=300,
    # CELERYD_TASK_SOFT_TIME_LIMIT=7,   # does not work under windows
    CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES=3600,
)

CELERY_IMPORTS=("tasks",)

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y

@app.task
def doNbsJob():
    print("Starting NbsJob now")
    time.sleep(60)
    #job_example.buildsw(loc)
    return("str: doNbsJob done")
```

Then I start the worker with:

```
d:\projekte\MOG_Arbeitshilfen\learningPython\celproj>celery -A tasks worker -l info
```

... and the celery beat (task-triggerer):

```
D:\projekte\MOG_Arbeitshilfen\learningPython\celproj>celery beat --loglevel=INFO
celery beat v3.1.18 (Cipater) is starting.
__    -    ... __   -        _
Configuration ->
    . broker -> amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672//
    . loader -> celery.loaders.default.Loader
    . scheduler -> celery.beat.PersistentScheduler
    . db -> celerybeat-schedule
    . logfile -> [stderr]@%INFO
    . maxinterval -> now (0s)
[2015-07-08 10:14:27,534: INFO/MainProcess] beat: Starting...
```

Unfortunately the tasks are never triggered - they don't appear on worker-output and neither on the beat-output

some additional information:
As broker I am using RabbitMQ server.
As backend I set up a postgresql-DB.
I am not using django.
    D:\celery_test\project>celery report

```
software -> celery:3.1.18 (Cipater) kombu:3.0.26 py:3.4.3
            billiard:3.3.0.20 py-amqp:1.4.6
platform -> system:Windows arch:32bit, WindowsPE imp:CPython
loader   -> celery.loaders.default.Loader
settings -> transport:amqp results:disabled
```

I would appreciate any help or hints from you.
Thank you in advance,
Lukas

Comment: Ok, now  I found something.                                                            I did it like it is said here:                                                                
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792101/how-to-configure-and-run-celerybeat
                                                                                   
But this is absolutely not the way it is described in the official celery-docutmentation :-/ ..?
<br><br>
The developement documentation contains some parst of this aproach, but also it is quite different.
Ok, well, whatever.. it seems to work for now..

Comment: ok, solved the problem now.
The app.conf.update(...) does not seem to work together when you start celery with the beat-option